# OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I defined a droid Arabic kufi in my WordPress website long time ago, as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.eot);
  src: url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

and it worked fine, suddenly the posts content disappeared, like in the image below.

[image]

Then when I inspect the element on chrome I have 30 warnings all the same:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi/v3/DroidKufi-Regular.woff2
>   ?p=2426:1 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT

Please will somebody help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: i have similar problem like you , did you find a solution?

Comment: dude that was 3 years ago, I'm surprised that I asked this question.